# Recursive type aliases with Pyright

Tags: type-alias, python-3.9, pyright

Checking the following code with Pyright:

```
from typing import Union, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
X_or_RecurListOf = Union[T, list['X_or_RecurListOf']]
x: X_or_RecurListOf[str] = ['asd']
```

produces the error:

```
  5:28 - error: Expression of type "list[str]" cannot be assigned to declared type "X_or_RecurListOf[str]"
    Type "list[str]" cannot be assigned to type "X_or_RecurListOf[str]"
      "list[str]" is incompatible with "str"
        TypeVar "_T@list" is invariant
          Type "str" cannot be assigned to type "X_or_RecurListOf[Type[T@X_or_RecurListOf]]"
            Type "str" cannot be assigned to type "T@X_or_RecurListOf"
            "str" is incompatible with "list[X_or_RecurListOf]" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
1 error, 0 warnings, 0 infos 
Completed in 0.677sec
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Or have I misunderstood the [announcement for support of recursive types in Pyright](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/pylance-introduces-five-new-features-that-enable-type-magic-for-python-developers/#1-support-for-recursive-type-aliases)?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I've found what Pyright stumbles over!

It wants to have the type parameter in the recursive definition:
`X_or_RecurListOf = Union[T, list['X_or_RecurListOf[T]']]` - pay attention to the `[T]`!

I don't see why this is necessary but it works for me, especially as I really meant `X_or_RecurListOf[T]` and not `X_or_RecurListOf[Any]`.